# Two different grouping levels in one select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this:

```
SELECT 
invoice_number, invoice_year, invoice_month, invoice_amount,
    payment_year, payment_month, payment_amount
FROM payments_table
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

So I have 4 invoices. The invoice amount of two invoices from 2015/01 add up to 900 and the 2 invoices from 2015/02 add up to 950

I want this result:

[image: Grouped]

So I want to sum the `invoice_amount` by `invoice_year` and `invoice_month` using the `invoice_number` just once. And I want to sum the `payment_amount` by `invoice_year`, `invoice_month`, `payment_year` and `payment_month`.

If I use `GROUP BY invoice_year, invoice_month, payment_year, payment_month` I get the right amounts for `SUM(payment_amount)` but I get the wrong amounts for `SUM(invoice_amount)`.

Any advice?

Comment: Your results don't make sense to me.  Why would payment month 4 include both invoices for the month?

Comment: If your data is like the sample you have shown, you can just do `SUM(DISTINCT invoice_amount)`.

Comment: @munircontractor that's dangerous, you are assuming two different invoices can't have the same invoice amount

Comment: In month 4 an amount of 200 was paid towards invoice #1002 and an amount of 200 was paid towards invoice #1003. Why does that not make sense?

Comment: @Rabbit yes...my bad... sorry

Comment: You really should have two tables: `Invoices` with one row per invoice and `Payments` with one row per payment. Then it becomes trivial to sum things up in any way you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution myself. Thanks all for thinking with me:

```
select b.invoice_year
, b.invoice_month
, b.invoice_amount
, c.payment_year
, c.payment_month
, c.payment_amount

from (
    select a.invoice_year
    , a.invoice_month
    , sum(a.invoice_amount) as invoice_amount

    from (
        select distinct invoice_number
        , invoice_year
        , invoice_month
        , invoice_amount 
        from payments
        ) a

    group by a.invoice_year
    , a.invoice_month
    ) b
inner join (
    select a.invoice_year
    , a.invoice_month
    , a.payment_year
    , a.payment_month
    , sum(a.payment_amount) as payment_amount

    from (
        select invoice_year
        , invoice_month
        , payment_year
        , payment_month
        , payment_amount 
        from payments
        ) a

    group by a.invoice_year
    , a.invoice_month
    , a.payment_year
    , a.payment_month
    ) as c
    on c.invoice_year = b.invoice_year
    and c.invoice_month = b.invoice_month
```

This gives me exactly the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The query you need is this one:

```
select a.invoice_year, a.invoice_month, a.payment_year, a.payment_month,
       SUM(payment_amount), b.sumup
  from payments_table a
        inner join
         (select invoice_year, invoice_month, sum(payment_amount) sumup
            from payments_table
           group by invoice_year, invoice_month) b
        ON (a.invoice_year = b.invoice_year
            and a.invoice_month = b.invoice_month )
 GROUP BY a.invoice_year, a.invoice_month, a.payment_year, a.payment_month
```

But let me say that for the sample data you provided the sum for `invoice_year and invoice_month` is total 900 not 950.

See it here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46249/4

Note that I did the fiddle in MySql but it should be the same for SQLServer since there is no specific function or syntax, just plain SQL. The reason why I did it in Mysql is because sometimes SQLFiddle with SQLServer gets unstable.

**EDIT**

Turns out that I was summing the wrong field and missing a column, so the proper query should be:

```
select a.invoice_year, a.invoice_month, 
       b.incount,
       SUM(payment_amount) invoice_amount,
       a.payment_year, 
       a.payment_month, 
       b.payment__amount
  from payments_table a
       inner join
       (select invoice_year, invoice_month, 
               count(distinct invoice_amount) incount, 
               sum(distinct invoice_amount) payment__amount
          from payments_table
        group by invoice_year, invoice_month) b
       ON (     a.invoice_year = b.invoice_year
           and  a.invoice_month = b.invoice_month )
 GROUP BY a.invoice_year, a.invoice_month, a.payment_year, a.payment_month
```

This will give you the results exactly as you want. See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46249/10

Comment: I get an error running this in SQL Server because the field b.sumup is not contained in the GROUP BY clause. We have 2 combinations of invoice_year and invoice_month. The sum of 2015/01 should be 900 (invoice #1001 = 500 + invoice #1002 = 400) and the sum of 2015/02 should be 950 (invoice #1003 = 600 + invoice #1004 = 350).

Comment: Your edit now does give the right invoice_amount per invoice_year and invoice_month but you are assuming that in a month an invoice_amount is unique. Selling the same product will result in many invoices with the same amount. In SQL Server I still get an error because columns are not in GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

in this sql fiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7d789/27, i broke down the components of your query and made a whole query out of the small parts to get what you want.

Comment: Consider posting and briefly explaining the query here. Your answer becomes unusable when SQL FIddle is down

Comment: It gives me payment_amounts that are twice the amount they should be. For example: The combination of invoice_year, invoice_month, payment_year, payment_month of 2015/01 and 2015/01 appears twice with payment_amounts of 100 and 50. So I should see 150. But I see 300.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this query.

```
SELECT Invoice_Year,
Invoice_Month,
CASE WHEN (SUM(Invoice_amount) <= 900 AND Invoice_Month=1 ) THEN 900 
WHEN (SUM(Invoice_amount) <= 950 AND Invoice_Month=2) THEN 950 END AS InvoiceAmount,
Payment_year,
Payment_Month,
SUM(Payment_Amount) as PaymentAmount
FROM @table 
GROUP BY 
Payment_Month,
Invoice_Month,
Invoice_Year,
Payment_year
ORDER BY Invoice_Month
```

Please find attached fiddle.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2463f/2)

Thank you

Comment: Consider posting and briefly explaining the query here. Your answer becomes unusable when SQL FIddle is down

Comment: This gives me exactly what I want but have hard coded the invoice_amounts. Those will differ in reality.

Comment: Actually I didn't got you. Can you be more specific. Actually I already hard coded Invoice _amount value here. but I don't know what exactly you want.